# Canvas Issues — scrolling and zooming while drawing (retaining perspective)

Tags: android, android-canvas

My issue is that I'm drawing rectangles to a screen and want to be able to scroll in a direction and continue drawing. This is meant to be a basic house plan drawing application.

I begin by drawing a square:

[image: 1]

I then click the <kbd>MOVE SCREEN</kbd> button and switch to "move mode". I pinch zoom out to draw the adjacent room:

[image: 2]

I then want to be able to draw this:

[image: 3]

However, as soon as I click <kbd>DRAW</kbd> mode and start drawing the second room, this happens:

[image: 4]

I.e. it reverts to the original zoom and draws in the wrong place. I realize its probably my code in the `onDraw()` method. Here's my code:

```
class HomerView extends View { // the custom View for drawing on

    // set up Bitmap, canvas, path and paint
    private Bitmap myBitmap; // the initial image we turn into our canvas
    private Canvas myCanvas; // the canvas we are drawing on
    private Rect myRect; // the mathematical path of the lines we draw
    private Paint myBitmapPaint; // the paint we use to draw the bitmap

    // get the width of the entire tablet screen
    private int screenWidth = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    // get the height of the entire tablet screen
    private int screenHeight = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;

    private int mX, mY, iX, iY; // current x,y and initial x,y
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;
    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public HomerView(Context context) { // constructor of HomerView
        super(context);
        myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // set our drawable space - the bitmap
                                          // which becomes the canvas we draw on
        myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap); // set our canvas to our bitmap which
                                         // we just set up
        myRect = new Rect(); // make a new rect
        myBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG); // set dither to ON in our
                                                      // saved drawing - gives
                                                      // better color
                                                      // interaction
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    public HomerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    public HomerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) { // method used when we want to draw
                                           // something to our canvas
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (addObjectMode == true || addApplianceMode == true) {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT); // sets canvas colour
            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmapPaint); // save the canvas
                                                              // to bitmap - the
                                                              // numbers are the
                                                              // x, y coords we
                                                              // are drawing
                                                              // from
            canvas.drawRect(myRect, myPaint); // draw the rectangle that the
                                              // user has drawn using the paint
                                              // we set up
        } else if (moveMode == true) {
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
            canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
            canvas.drawBitmap(myBitmap, 0, 0, myBitmapPaint); // if not present
                                                              // - nothing is
                                                              // moved
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) { // if
                                                                     // screen
                                                                     // size
                                                                     // changes,
                                                                     // alter
                                                                     // the
                                                                     // bitmap
                                                                     // size
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    private void touch_Start(float x, float y) { // on finger touchdown
        // check touch mode
        iX = (int) (Math.round(x));
        iY = (int) (Math.round(y));
        mX = (int) (Math.round(x));
        mY = (int) (Math.round(y));
        if (addObjectMode == true) {
            myRect.set(iX, iY, mX, mY);
        } else if (addApplianceMode == true) {
            // code to draw an appliance icon at mX, mY (with offset so icon is
            // centered)
            if (isLamp == true) {
                Resources res = getResources();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.lamp);
                myCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, iX - 50, iY - 50, myBitmapPaint);
            } else if (isPC == true) {
                Resources res = getResources();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.pc);
                myCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, iX - 50, iY - 50, myBitmapPaint);
            } else if (isKettle == true) {
                Resources res = getResources();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.kettle);
                myCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, iX - 50, iY - 50, myBitmapPaint);
            } else if (isOven == true) {
                Resources res = getResources();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.oven);
                myCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, iX - 50, iY - 50, myBitmapPaint);
            } else if (isTV == true) {
                Resources res = getResources();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.tv);
                myCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, iX - 50, iY - 50, myBitmapPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    private void touch_Move(float x, float y) { // on finger movement
        float dX = Math.abs(x - mX); // get difference between x and my X
        float dY = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dX >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dY >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) { // if coordinates
                                                              // are outside
                                                              // screen? if
                                                              // touching hard
                                                              // enough?
            mX = (int) (Math.round(x));
            mY = (int) (Math.round(y));
            if (addObjectMode == true) {
                myRect.set(iX, iY, mX, mY);
            }
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void touch_Up() { // on finger release
        if (addObjectMode == true) {
            myRect.set(iX, iY, mX, mY);
            myCanvas.drawRect(iX, iY, mX, mY, myPaint);
            if (eraseMode == false) {
                dialogStarter();
            }
        } else if (addApplianceMode == true) {
            showDialog(DIALOG_DEVICE_ENTRY);
        }
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) { // on any touch event
        if (addObjectMode == true || addApplianceMode == true) {

            float x = event.getX(); // get current X
            float y = event.getY(); // get current Y

            switch (event.getAction()) { // what action is the user performing?
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: // if user is touching down
                touch_Start(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // if user is moving finger while
                                          // touched down
                touch_Move(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: // if user has released finger
                touch_Up();
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            return true;
        } else if (moveMode == true) {
            mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            final int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                final float x = event.getX();
                final float y = event.getY();
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(0);
                invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                final int pointerIndex = event
                        .findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
                final float x = event.getX(pointerIndex);
                final float y = event.getY(pointerIndex);

                // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a
                // gesture.
                if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                    final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                    final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;
                    mPosX += dx;
                    mPosY += dy;
                    invalidate();
                }
                mLastTouchX = x;
                mLastTouchY = y;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
                mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
                final int pointerIndex = (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
                final int pointerId = event.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
                if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                    // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                    // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                    final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                    mLastTouchX = event.getX(newPointerIndex);
                    mLastTouchY = event.getY(newPointerIndex);
                    mActivePointerId = event.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
                }
                break;
            }
            }
            invalidate();
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void drawApplianceIcon() {
        myCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, iX - 50, iY - 50, myBitmapPaint);
        makeToast("BMP drawn to canvas = " + bmp);
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone pick apart my code so that I can draw straight on the zoomed or panned image? Am I barking up the wrong tree and should I just use a vertical and horizontal scroll bar? Zooming isn't strictly necessary.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your onDraw isn't scaling the canvas when in non-move mode.  That means as soon as you go into any other mode, you lose the scaling factor permanently.  You need to fix that.

Comment: Take the scroll and zoom code from the other branch of the if statement and make it apply to both modes.  So long as you aren't doing background rendering on another thread (something you should only do if you hit a performance bottleneck), scaling everything globally is fine.

Comment: I amended it so that it always included canvas.scale and canvas.translate commands. However, my drawing actions aren't being correctly offset now - i.e. I still draw relative to the initial Zoom level.

Comment: You may need to scale your rects as well.